# Android ListView not scrolling due to use of Fragment instead of ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I had set up an Activity and a Fragment, and in the layout I had a ListView, which I gave an arbitrary name and accessed via findViewById(). All was working fine, until I noticed that scrolling didn't work for the ListView.

There are many threads here on SO about ListView and lack of scrolling. I used much more time than I care to admit trying out one possible solution after another. Nothing worked, until I stumbled upon the solution, which I'll describe in an answer to this question.

EDIT:

I've deleted the answer I posted to my own question, where I claimed that you had to use ListFragment (or SherlockListFragment) to get scrolling of a ListView to work.

Thanks to Zackehh9lives I've determined that I was wrong in that claim.

The key phrase in his answer is that the stump of code he shows is in the onCreateView() method. After some experimenting, I think the situation is as follows:

If you use ListFragment (or SherlockListFragment) you have to set up the ListView widget in the onActivityCreated() method, and ListView scrolling works.

If you use Fragment (or SherlockFragment) you can set up ListView in onActivityCreated() or in onCreateView(), but if you do it in onActivityCreated() then scrolling doesn't work.

That was my problem - I was using SherlockFragment and setting up ListView in onActivityCreated().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a `ListView` in a `SherlockFragment` and it scrolls just fine. Not sure what the issue is? Perhaps you just have a something incorrect somewhere (might want to post your code?). Below is my ListView and XML:

**MyFragment.java:**

```
// Find the ListView we're using
list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
// Set the vertical edges to fade when scrolling
list.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);

// Create a new adapter
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.title, questions);
// Set the adapter to the list
list.setAdapter(adapter);

// Set on item click listener to the ListView
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

All that code is all I have related to my ListView in the Fragment, and it's in my `onCreateView()`. Below is the XML for it.

**ListItem.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:textColor="#7F7F7F"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_next" />
```

**ListView.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:paddingTop="-2dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you post your code, we have a better chance at helping :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had tried many other things, and then became very sure that the problem was the different fragment type. That's why I posted this in the "answer your own question format". Unfortunately, I've moved on and it will take me a bit of time to recreate the situation I had yesterday when I posted this. I'll get back to you a bit later.